# What is wrong with my libsnark compliance predicate program?

Tags: c, proof

This fails in the verification step when the shift amount (sham) is 1. I'm not really seeing why that is. I've read the constraint and witness generators dozens of times without spotting the bug/discrepancy.

What the code is "proving" is that a particular number can be obtained by starting from 0 and shifting in bits at the end.

```
// The following code file is mainly cobbled together from bits of
// libsnark. It is hereby released under the MIT license, but it is
// not itself part of libsnark as some of the copy-pasted file headers
// would indicate.

/**
*****************************************************************************
* @author     This file is part of libsnark, developed by SCIPR Lab
*             and contributors (see AUTHORS).
* @copyright  MIT license (see LICENSE file)
*****************************************************************************/
#include <libsnark/common/default_types/r1cs_ppzkpcd_pp.hpp>

/** @file
*****************************************************************************

Declaration of functionality that runs the R1CS single-predicate ppzkPCD
for a compliance predicate example.

*****************************************************************************
* @author     This file is part of libsnark, developed by SCIPR Lab
*             and contributors (see AUTHORS).
* @copyright  MIT license (see LICENSE file)
*****************************************************************************/

#ifndef RUN_R1CS_SP_PPZKPCD_HPP_
#define RUN_R1CS_SP_PPZKPCD_HPP_

#include <cstddef>

namespace libsnark {

  /**
   * Runs the single-predicate ppzkPCD (generator, prover, and verifier) for the
   * "tally compliance predicate", of a given wordsize, arity, and depth.
   *
   * Optionally, also test the serialization routines for keys and proofs.
   * (This takes additional time.)
   */
  template<typename PCD_ppT>
  bool run_r1cs_sp_ppzkpcd_tally_example(const size_t value,
                                         const bool test_serialization);

} // libsnark

/** @file
*****************************************************************************

Implementation of functionality that runs the R1CS single-predicate ppzkPCD
for a compliance predicate example.

See run_r1cs_sp_ppzkpcd.hpp .

*****************************************************************************
* @author     This file is part of libsnark, developed by SCIPR Lab
*             and contributors (see AUTHORS).
* @copyright  MIT license (see LICENSE file)
*****************************************************************************/

#ifndef RUN_R1CS_SP_PPZKPCD_TCC_
#define RUN_R1CS_SP_PPZKPCD_TCC_

/** @file
*****************************************************************************

Declaration of interfaces for the tally compliance predicate.

The tally compliance predicate has two purposes:
(1) it exemplifies the use of interfaces declared in cp_handler.hpp, and
(2) it enables us to test r1cs_pcd functionalities.

See
- libsnark/zk_proof_systems/pcd/r1cs_pcd/r1cs_sp_ppzkpcd/examples/run_r1cs_sp_ppzkpcd.hpp
- libsnark/zk_proof_systems/pcd/r1cs_pcd/r1cs_mp_ppzkpcd/examples/run_r1cs_mp_ppzkpcd.hpp
for code that uses the tally compliance predicate.

*****************************************************************************
* @author     This file is part of libsnark, developed by SCIPR Lab
*             and contributors (see AUTHORS).
* @copyright  MIT license (see LICENSE file)
*****************************************************************************/

#ifndef TALLY_CP_HPP_
#define TALLY_CP_HPP_

#include <libsnark/gadgetlib1/gadgets/basic_gadgets.hpp>
#include <libsnark/zk_proof_systems/pcd/r1cs_pcd/compliance_predicate/compliance_predicate.hpp>
#include <libsnark/zk_proof_systems/pcd/r1cs_pcd/compliance_predicate/cp_handler.hpp>

namespace libsnark {

  /**
   * Subclasses a R1CS PCD message to the tally compliance predicate.
   */
  template<typename FieldT>
  class tally_pcd_message : public r1cs_pcd_message<FieldT> {
  public:
    size_t value;

    tally_pcd_message(const size_t type,
                      const size_t value);
    r1cs_variable_assignment<FieldT> payload_as_r1cs_variable_assignment() const;
    void print() const;

    ~tally_pcd_message() = default;
  };

  template<typename FieldT>
  class tally_pcd_local_data : public r1cs_pcd_local_data<FieldT> {
  public:
    bool lowbit;

    tally_pcd_local_data(const bool lowbit);
    r1cs_variable_assignment<FieldT> as_r1cs_variable_assignment() const;
    void print() const;

    ~tally_pcd_local_data() = default;
  };

  /**
   * Subclass a R1CS compliance predicate handler to the tally compliance predicate handler.
   */
  template<typename FieldT>
  class tally_cp_handler : public compliance_predicate_handler<FieldT, protoboard<FieldT> > {
  public:
    typedef compliance_predicate_handler<FieldT, protoboard<FieldT> > base_handler;

    tally_cp_handler(const size_t type,
                     const bool relies_on_same_type_inputs = false,
                     const std::set<size_t> accepted_input_types = std::set<size_t>());

    void generate_r1cs_constraints();
    void generate_r1cs_witness(const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<r1cs_pcd_message<FieldT> > > &incoming_messages,
                               const std::shared_ptr<r1cs_pcd_local_data<FieldT> > &local_data);

    r1cs_pcd_message<FieldT>* get_base_case_message() const;
  };

} // libsnark

/** @file
*****************************************************************************

Implementation of interfaces for the tally compliance predicate.

See tally_cp.hpp .

*****************************************************************************
* @author     This file is part of libsnark, developed by SCIPR Lab
*             and contributors (see AUTHORS).
* @copyright  MIT license (see LICENSE file)
*****************************************************************************/

#ifndef TALLY_CP_TCC_
#define TALLY_CP_TCC_

#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

#include <libff/algebra/fields/field_utils.hpp>

namespace libsnark {

  template<typename FieldT>
  tally_pcd_message<FieldT>::tally_pcd_message(const size_t type,
                                               const size_t value) :
    r1cs_pcd_message<FieldT>(type), value(value)
  {
  }

  template<typename FieldT>
  r1cs_variable_assignment<FieldT> tally_pcd_message<FieldT>::payload_as_r1cs_variable_assignment() const
  {
    r1cs_variable_assignment<FieldT> result;
  
    result.push_back(value);
  
    return result;
  }

  template<typename FieldT>
  void tally_pcd_message<FieldT>::print() const
  {
    printf("Tally message of type %zu:\n", this->type);
    printf("  value: %zu\n", value);
  }

  template<typename FieldT>
  tally_pcd_local_data<FieldT>::tally_pcd_local_data(const bool lowbit) :
    lowbit(lowbit)
  {
  }

  template<typename FieldT>
  r1cs_variable_assignment<FieldT> tally_pcd_local_data<FieldT>::as_r1cs_variable_assignment() const
  {
    const r1cs_variable_assignment<FieldT> result = { FieldT(lowbit ? FieldT::one() : FieldT::zero()) };
    return result;
  }

  template<typename FieldT>
  void tally_pcd_local_data<FieldT>::print() const
  {
    printf("Tally PCD local data:\n");
    printf("  lowbit: %zu\n", lowbit);
  }

  template<typename FieldT>
  class tally_pcd_message_variable: public r1cs_pcd_message_variable<FieldT> {
  public:
    pb_variable<FieldT> value;

    tally_pcd_message_variable(protoboard<FieldT> &pb,
                               const std::string &annotation_prefix) :
      r1cs_pcd_message_variable<FieldT>(pb, annotation_prefix)
    {
      value.allocate(pb, FMT(annotation_prefix, " value"));

      this->update_all_vars();
    }

    std::shared_ptr<r1cs_pcd_message<FieldT> > get_message() const
    {
      const size_t type_val = this->pb.val(this->type).as_ulong();
      const size_t value_val = this->pb.val(this->value).as_ulong();

      std::shared_ptr<r1cs_pcd_message<FieldT> > result;
      result.reset(new tally_pcd_message<FieldT>(type_val, value_val));
      return result;
    }

    ~tally_pcd_message_variable() = default;
  };

  template<typename FieldT>
  class tally_pcd_local_data_variable : public r1cs_pcd_local_data_variable<FieldT> {
  public:

    pb_variable<FieldT> lowbit;

    tally_pcd_local_data_variable(protoboard<FieldT> &pb,
                                  const std::string &annotation_prefix) :
      r1cs_pcd_local_data_variable<FieldT>(pb, annotation_prefix)
    {
      lowbit.allocate(pb, FMT(annotation_prefix, " lowbit"));

      this->update_all_vars();
    }

    std::shared_ptr<r1cs_pcd_local_data<FieldT> > get_local_data() const
    {
      const size_t lowbit_val = this->pb.val(lowbit).as_ulong();

      std::shared_ptr<r1cs_pcd_local_data<FieldT> > result;
      result.reset(new tally_pcd_local_data<FieldT>(lowbit_val));
      return result;
    }

    ~tally_pcd_local_data_variable() = default;
  };

  template<typename FieldT>
  tally_cp_handler<FieldT>::tally_cp_handler(const size_t type,
                                             const bool relies_on_same_type_inputs,
                                             const std::set<size_t> accepted_input_types) :
    compliance_predicate_handler<FieldT, protoboard<FieldT> >(protoboard<FieldT>(),
                                                              type*100,
                                                              type,
                                                              1,
                                                              relies_on_same_type_inputs,
                                                              accepted_input_types)
  {
    this->outgoing_message.reset(new tally_pcd_message_variable<FieldT>(this->pb, "outgoing_message"));
  
    this->incoming_messages[0].reset(new tally_pcd_message_variable<FieldT>(this->pb, "incoming_message"));
  
    this->local_data.reset(new tally_pcd_local_data_variable<FieldT>(this->pb, "local_data"));
  
    (new pb_variable<FieldT>())->allocate(this->pb); // apparently needed to work around a libsnark bug - compliance predicate must have additional variables
  }

  template<typename FieldT>
  void tally_cp_handler<FieldT>::generate_r1cs_constraints()
  {
    generate_boolean_r1cs_constraint<FieldT>(this->pb, std::dynamic_pointer_cast<tally_pcd_local_data_variable<FieldT> >(this->local_data)->lowbit, "lowbit_is_boolean");

    this->pb.add_r1cs_constraint(r1cs_constraint<FieldT>(1,
                                                         (2 * std::dynamic_pointer_cast<tally_pcd_message_variable<FieldT> >(this->incoming_messages[0])->value) + std::dynamic_pointer_cast<tally_pcd_local_data_variable<FieldT> >(this->local_data)->lowbit,
                                                         std::dynamic_pointer_cast<tally_pcd_message_variable<FieldT> >(this->outgoing_message)->value));
  }

  template<typename FieldT>
  void tally_cp_handler<FieldT>::generate_r1cs_witness(const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<r1cs_pcd_message<FieldT> > > &incoming_messages,
                                                       const std::shared_ptr<r1cs_pcd_local_data<FieldT> > &local_data)
  {
    base_handler::generate_r1cs_witness(incoming_messages, local_data);
    auto im = incoming_messages[0];
    auto tm = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<tally_pcd_message<FieldT> >(im);
    std::cerr << ((size_t)(tm.get())) << std::endl;
    auto vl = tm->value;
    size_t value_in_x2_val = (vl << 1);
    size_t value_in_x2_pl_val = value_in_x2_val + ((std::dynamic_pointer_cast<tally_pcd_local_data<FieldT> >(local_data)->lowbit) ? 1 : 0);
    this->pb.val(std::dynamic_pointer_cast<tally_pcd_message_variable<FieldT> >(this->outgoing_message)->type) = 1;
    this->pb.val(std::dynamic_pointer_cast<tally_pcd_message_variable<FieldT> >(this->outgoing_message)->value) = value_in_x2_pl_val;
  }

  template<typename FieldT>
  r1cs_pcd_message<FieldT>* tally_cp_handler<FieldT>::get_base_case_message() const
  {
    return (new tally_pcd_message<FieldT>(0, 0));
  }

} // libsnark

#endif // TALLY_CP_TCC_

#endif // TALLY_CP_HPP_

#include <libsnark/zk_proof_systems/pcd/r1cs_pcd/r1cs_sp_ppzkpcd/r1cs_sp_ppzkpcd.hpp>

namespace libsnark {
  
  template<typename PCD_ppT>
  bool run_r1cs_sp_ppzkpcd_tally_example(const size_t value,
                                         const bool test_serialization)
  {
    libff::enter_block("Call to run_r1cs_sp_ppzkpcd_tally_example");

    typedef libff::Fr<typename PCD_ppT::curve_A_pp> FieldT;

    bool all_accept = true;

    libff::enter_block("Generate compliance predicate");
    const size_t type = 1;
    tally_cp_handler<FieldT> tally(type);
    tally.generate_r1cs_constraints();
    r1cs_pcd_compliance_predicate<FieldT> tally_cp = tally.get_compliance_predicate();
    libff::leave_block("Generate compliance predicate");

    libff::print_header("R1CS ppzkPCD Generator");
    r1cs_sp_ppzkpcd_keypair<PCD_ppT> keypair = r1cs_sp_ppzkpcd_generator<PCD_ppT>(tally_cp);

    libff::print_header("Process verification key");
    r1cs_sp_ppzkpcd_processed_verification_key<PCD_ppT> pvk = r1cs_sp_ppzkpcd_process_vk<PCD_ppT>(keypair.vk);

    if (test_serialization)
      {
        libff::enter_block("Test serialization of keys");
        keypair.pk = libff::reserialize<r1cs_sp_ppzkpcd_proving_key<PCD_ppT> >(keypair.pk);
        keypair.vk = libff::reserialize<r1cs_sp_ppzkpcd_verification_key<PCD_ppT> >(keypair.vk);
        pvk = libff::reserialize<r1cs_sp_ppzkpcd_processed_verification_key<PCD_ppT> >(pvk);
        libff::leave_block("Test serialization of keys");
      }
    r1cs_sp_ppzkpcd_proof<PCD_ppT> proof; // start out with an empty proof
    std::shared_ptr<r1cs_pcd_message<FieldT> > msg;
    msg.reset(tally.get_base_case_message());
    for (size_t sham = 0; sham < 32; sham++) {
      fprintf(stderr, "sham=%zu\n", sham);
      bool lowbit = ((value & (1 << (31 - sham))) ? true : false);
      std::shared_ptr<r1cs_pcd_local_data<FieldT> > ld;
      ld.reset(new tally_pcd_local_data<FieldT>(lowbit));
      std::vector<std::shared_ptr<r1cs_pcd_message<FieldT> > > msgs;
      std::cerr << ((size_t)(msg.get())) << std::endl;
      msgs.push_back(msg);
      std::cerr << ((size_t)(msgs[0].get())) << std::endl;
      tally.generate_r1cs_witness(msgs, ld);
      const r1cs_pcd_compliance_predicate_primary_input<FieldT> tally_primary_input(tally.get_outgoing_message());
      const r1cs_pcd_compliance_predicate_auxiliary_input<FieldT> tally_auxiliary_input(msgs, ld, tally.get_witness());
      libff::print_header("R1CS ppzkPCD Prover");
      std::vector<r1cs_sp_ppzkpcd_proof<PCD_ppT> > proofs;
      proofs.push_back(proof);
      proof = r1cs_sp_ppzkpcd_prover<PCD_ppT>(keypair.pk, tally_primary_input, tally_auxiliary_input, proofs);
      if (test_serialization)
        {
          libff::enter_block("Test serialization of proof");
          proof = libff::reserialize<r1cs_sp_ppzkpcd_proof<PCD_ppT> >(proof);
          libff::leave_block("Test serialization of proof");
        }
      msg = tally.get_outgoing_message();
      printf("Outgoing message is:\n");
      msg->print();
      libff::print_header("R1CS ppzkPCD Verifier");
      const r1cs_sp_ppzkpcd_primary_input<PCD_ppT> pcd_verifier_input(msg);
      const bool ans = r1cs_sp_ppzkpcd_verifier<PCD_ppT>(keypair.vk, pcd_verifier_input, proof);
      if (!ans) { fprintf(stderr, "OOPS!\n"); exit(1); }
      libff::print_header("R1CS ppzkPCD Online Verifier");
      const bool ans2 = r1cs_sp_ppzkpcd_online_verifier<PCD_ppT>(pvk, pcd_verifier_input, proof);
      if (!ans2) { fprintf(stderr, "OOPS!\n"); exit(1); }
      printf("\n");
      printf("Current node = %zu. Current proof verifies = %s\n", sham, ans ? "YES" : "NO");
      printf("\n\n\n ================================================================================\n\n\n");
    }
    libff::leave_block("Call to run_r1cs_sp_ppzkpcd_tally_example");
    return all_accept;
  }

} // libsnark

#endif // RUN_R1CS_SP_PPZKPCD_TCC_

#endif // RUN_R1CS_SP_PPZKPCD_HPP_

using namespace libsnark;

template<typename PCD_ppT>
void test_tally()
{
  const bool test_serialization = false;
  const bool bit = run_r1cs_sp_ppzkpcd_tally_example<PCD_ppT>(123456789, test_serialization);
  if (!bit) { fprintf(stderr, "OOPS!\n"); exit(1); }
}

int main(void)
{
  typedef default_r1cs_ppzkpcd_pp PCD_pp;

  libff::start_profiling();
  PCD_pp::init_public_params();

  test_tally<PCD_pp>();
}
```

Comment: It's something wrong with the 2x+bit constraint. When that constraint is commented out, it can validate the proofs successfully. Maybe I'm not understanding how r1cs works.

Comment: Actually it still fails, only later. Very mystifying.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, found the problem.

One needs

```
this->arity.allocate(this->pb, "arity");
```

in the constructor.